# Using drop down list linked to macros

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time using a drop down list. I was wondering if there was a way to assign a macro to each of the items in the drop down list.

[image]

For an example if I selected BZ1A I would want it to run the sub I have called BZ1A.

Comment: You have a single event handler which catches the change, and then looks at the selected item to decide what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Run Macros From Drop Down

- Copy the first code into the sheet module of the worksheet containing the drop down, e.g. `Sheet1` (the name in parentheses in the `VBE Project Explorer`).
- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- Put your codes into the same module, e.g. `Module1`. Otherwise you will have to modify the code.
- In this example the drop down list is in cell `A1` of worksheet `Sheet1` and contains the list (values) `Sub1`, `Sub2`, `Sub3`.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const CellAddress As String = "A1"
    Const ModuleName As String = "Module1"
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Range(CellAddress), Target) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            On Error GoTo clearError
            Application.Run ModuleName & "." & Target.Value
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1` (Example)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sub1()
    MsgBox "Running 'Sub1'"
End Sub
Sub Sub2()
    MsgBox "Running 'Sub2'"
End Sub
Sub Sub3()
    MsgBox "Running 'Sub3'"
End Sub
```